# What is more efficient, few small related tables or one big?

Tags: sql

I have information about a `Shop`. It belongs, to a `City`. `City` belongs to the `Country`. And `Country` belongs to a `Continent`.

Should I make one big table that contains 4 columns with information about every `Shop`. Or should I make 4 tables. First with `Continent` column. Second with `Country` and it's relation to a `Continent`. Third with a `City` and it's relation to a `Country`. Finally fourth with a `Shop` and it's relation to a `City`.

What is the best approach?

Comment: I think this will be your best and minimal solution (3 tables).
1. country => id, title, code, continent_title
2. city=> id, title, code, country_id
3. shop=>id, city_id

Comment: I agree with @Jakir Hossen and have the continent in the same table for the county. In terms of efficiency you can also consider indexing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the usual approach to this would be to use separate tables linked with foreign keys.

Why? Well lets say you open 10 new shops. Sure you could just add their details to your shop table but the more shops you open and the harder placenames are to spell, the more likely it is that errors will creep in. Having a linked table means you have a **single version of the truth**. In other words you have Mississippi once, and no risk of also having Misissippi or Missisippi.

Not only that but in the one table approach you are storing country, city, continent using text. So if your shop inventory or sales get big and you want to generate a report by city or country, that query is going to get slow really quickly.

By having a seperate table with an integer primary key, SQL can search really fast for sales in that city, or country. Not only that but it's easier to create reports such as all sales by shop for City x or Country x.

Comment: I'd add that whilst integer primary keys are the most common and easiest to implement, it is entirely legitimate to have other data types as your key, provided the values are unique. `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in SQL Server (basically a GUID) is often used as well. There are considerations regarding indexing and query efficiency to consider but that's another topic altogether.

Comment: I have a lot of `NVARCHAR` primary keys because I have a loading function and using integers is pain in the ass. Will it harm my database really hard if the tables with primary keys are relatively small but with foreign keys will rise over time to tens of thousands of records?

Comment: The "harm" is just in the relative speed of processing of NVARCHAR vs Int. It's going to depend on your hardware and indexing as to how much of a hit that is.